# What is this deviation from Dependency Injection called?

Tags: javascript

Looking into Dependency Injection in JavaScript, as with Angular, I decided that true DI was overkill for my medium sized project, so I worked on a simpler way to organize my project and implement Inversion of Control.

I felt interfaces aren't really worth the extra syntax since JavaScript has so few data types to deal with, and it's really easy to type check in JS without the help of interfaces. And I felt that it was unnecessary to define different variations of services (factories, etc), and I instead treat every element as a simple service, which can depend on any other service(s). I'm pretty sure the result would not be called DI.

So what would I call this pattern? And can this be considered a form of IoC?

```
var Directory = function() {
  this.directories = {};
  this.items = {};
}
var root = new Directory();

//File projects/my-project-1/libraries/depends.js
var Service = function(name, dependencies, func) {
  this.dependencyCollection = [];
  this.func;
  for (var x = 0; x < dependencies.length; x++) {
    var nameSegments = dependencies[x].split(' / ');
    var service = root;
    var servicePlaceholder = service;
    for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
      var segment = nameSegments[i];
      if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
        if (servicePlaceholder.items[segment]) {
          this.dependencyCollection.push(servicePlaceholder.items[segment]);
        } else {
          throw 'Dependent item missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.items, null, 3) + ' (' + dependencies + ": " + segment + ')';
        }
      } else if (servicePlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        servicePlaceholder = servicePlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        throw 'Dependent directory missing: ' + JSON.stringify(servicePlaceholder.directories, null, 3) + ' (' + segment + ')';
      }
    }
  }
  var directory = root;
  var directoryPlaceholder = directory;
  var nameSegments = name.split(' / ');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameSegments.length; i++) {
    var segment = nameSegments[i];
    if (i === nameSegments.length - 1) {
      directoryPlaceholder.items[segment] = func.apply(null, this.dependencyCollection);
      this.init = function() {
        func.apply(null, this.dependencyCollection);
      }
    } else {
      if (directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment]) {
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      } else {
        directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment] = new Directory();
        directoryPlaceholder = directoryPlaceholder.directories[segment];
      }
    }
  }
}

//File: projects/my-project-1/js/selectors/button-1.js
var button = new Service('selectors / button-1', [], function() {
  return $('.button');
});

//File: projects/my-project-1/js/selectors/body.js
var body = new Service('selectors / body', [], function() {
  return $('body');
});

//File: projects/my-project-1/js/handlers/handler-1.js
var handler = new Service('handlers / handler-1', ['selectors / button-1', 'selectors / body'], function(button, body) {
  button.on('click', function() {
    body.css({
      'background-color': 'green'
    });
  });
}).init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [service locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).  It's not dependency injection at all.  This is an elaborate key value store where the keys use `/` as a delimiter.  I don't see how this helps inject dependencies. It hides dependencies. This is a place to stash global objects.

Comment: Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to build or [find the service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), is the fundamental requirement of the pattern (DI). - I have a hard time getting my head around what exactly the difference is between finding it and passing it. In my mind, since the service itself (the function) isn't finding the dependency, its *constructor* is passing it to the function (right?), it seems to meet that description in my mind. But Im here to ask, not tell.

Comment: You're quoting from wikipedias [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) page.  What that means is I should be able to look at a client and find no clues about where the service comes from.  If the client calls something that finds the service then it knows how to find the service.  that means the client CARES where the service is. Which means you can't change the location of the service without pissing off the client.  Using a service locator mitigates this only a little, by ensuring that you'd have to move the locator to piss off the client.

Comment: Dependency injection leaves a client caring only about the actual dependencies it needs.  Not how to make them, or how to find them, or what to call to get them.  A real DI client just asks to be handed it's dependencies.

Comment: Okkk that makes sense now. Ive asked a few questions about the definition of DI and no answer ever quite put it that way.

Comment: @CandiedOrange the service locator is a type of DI, it's just a type of DI that makes things harder to mock when you need to.

Comment: @RubberDuck not according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte), or [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection), the guy who gave us these terms.

Comment: What you're saying seems to make sense to me, but that left me wondering how a real JS DI library (Angular) manages to inject a dependency without the service's constructor being told what the dependency is called. Maybe you could clarify? [AngularJS's approach](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) seems to supply a name for the dependency similar (if not identical) to how my code does it, except they don't include scope in the dependency name: `someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);`

Comment: @RubberDuck, "the service locator is a type of DI". No, no and thrice no! DI involves telling a thing what its dependencies are. Service locators require that thing ask for them. They are complete opposites of each other.

Comment: @DavidArno Its confusing no matter how much I think about it, it just seems like the constructor finds them but the *service*, the result of the constructor, simply receives them without looking anywhere. Its seems to me the `Service` constructor in my code acts as an injector.